# How to put form-groups into an array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with dynamic fields. A field is added through a rendered partial. I'd like the output of the form group to be an array of hashes:

`task: { responses: [{text: "asdf", option: 1},{text: "qwer", option: 5} ... ]}`

Is it possible to do this through the form helper `_tag`s or do I need to do something different? Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my partial:

```
<% if local_assigns.has_key?(:res) %>
<div class="task-response form-group">

  <%= label_tag :text, "Text", :class => 'label-control' %>
  <%= text_field_tag "task[responses][]", '', :class => 'form-control', :value => res %>

  <% if local_assigns.has_key?(:tasks) %>

    <%= label_tag :option, "Option", :class => 'label-control' %>
    <%= select_tag "task[responses][]", options_for_select(tasks.collect {|t| [t.title, t.id]}), :class => 'form-control' %>

  <% end %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by putting an empty array in front of the desired hash keys:

```
<%= text_field_tag "task[responses][][text]" ... %>
<%= select_tag "task[responses][][next]" ... %>
```

gives:

`task: { responses: [{text: "asdf", option: 1},{text: "qwer", option: 5} ... ]}`